# How do I use pointer-events to react only to scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Is it possible to set pointer-events to only react to scrolling or drag on a touch-pad? I have a div 'in the way' for scrolling a complex html arrangement* and I would like to know if I can limit the pointer events to only react to scroll / mouse wheel actions.

I am interested in knowing whether I understand this correctly. If `pointer-events:none;` means that all events are void, how can I kill all events but leave one active?

I have set up an HTML area that is bigger than the box it fits in, but if I were to show the scroll bar, it would seem higher than it should be because of a pop-up (position:top) element. This area still needs to be scrolled so to achieve this I have used jQuery to make my 'box to scroll' follow an invisible div within a div:

```
<div id="scrollcontrol"style="overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;position:absolute;
   top:12px;left:180px;width:40px;height:1300px;">
   <div id="catscrollpos"style="position:absolute;
    top:0px;width:200px;height:2250px;">
   </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$('#scrollcontrol').scroll(function({
  $('#rangetable').css({
  'top':$('#catscrollpos').position().top+'px'
  });
});
```

Comment: The property originates from the SVG-spec and for HTML-elements it is still very limited (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). The only supported values for `pointer-events` on HTML-elements are `none`, which makes the element ignore pointer-events completely (though the events may bubble to parent-elements beneath the element), and `auto` which sets the default behaviour.

Comment: please check if you can use the scroll events of touch devices. http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_scroll.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for specification in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):

When an element has applied `pointer-events: none;`

The element is **never** the target of **any** mouse events and any events are void;

Please look at this demonstration:

http://jsbin.com/wewosumehi/1/

Events are not being fired, you cannot even scroll the `container`.

Comment: oh this is such a shame

Comment: This answers the question as asked, but I, and I am sure the OP, am wondering if there is any other way to accomplish this. Basically, is there any equivalent to "pointer-events: none" that still allows for scrolling? I would also like the scrollbar to be clickable, but I'm not sure about the OP.

Comment: So, is there a way of restricting all mouse events except scrolling?

Comment: > Events are not being fired, you cannot even scroll the container. -- Except `body`. Body DOES scroll when `pointer-events: none;` is applied to it.

Comment: having the same issue here, i need to prevent all the fields inside the container from being edited but the scroll event has to be triggered in order for the user to view the current values, any changes on that?

Comment: you can re-enable pointer-events on child elements, by putting `pointer-events:auto;` on them, so I thought you'd be able to do the same for scroll bars but I'm struggling to find how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Today I also faced same issue. I want to disable click events but allow scroll.

My Old code:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 540px; overflow: auto; pointer-events: none;">
<table></table>
</div>
```

I cannot able to scroll because of pointer-events: none; So I have added overflow to div element and pointer-event to table element. It fixed the scroll problem.

Solution:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 540px; overflow: auto">
<table style="pointer-events: none;"></table>
</div>
```