# Allow pointer (click) events to pass through element whilst maintaining scroll facility

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

My goal is to have an element which allows:

1. elements underneath to be clicked on/interacted with,
2. scrolling

The solution to 1 is widely known to be `pointer-events: none`. This is as described in [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements).

However, the element can not be scrolled, because the scroll bar appears on the element with `pointer-events: none`. This can be seen in this example: http://jsbin.com/madure/2/edit?html,css,output.

Is there a workaround to this, or is it something that would need to be addressed at the browser level? Perhaps with an additional rule, `pointer-events: scrollOnly`.

Comment: Are you ok with it not blocking mouse events over/leave, and CSS states like hover? If so, I can provide a CSS-only solution that will block all click-type mouse/pointer events on the parent. Let me know and I will post the solution.

Comment: @csuwldcat I would like all pointer events other than scroll/mousewheel (or a click on the scrollbar itself) for my use case, so hover is needed. However it may be worth posting anyway as it could help others. :-)

Comment: Hello Oliver, I am facing the exact same issue as you are. I need to scroll on a div, but let every other events "pass through" to the divs behind it. Have you solved your problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> The pointer-events CSS property specifies under what circumstances (if
>   any) a particular graphic element can become the target of **mouse**
>   **events.**

So basically if you make the upper layer *insensitive* for click it will be so for wheel events too. I suggest on of two things

**JavaScript workaround:**
Which basically use the fact that:

> Note that preventing an element from being the target of mouse events
>   by using pointer-events does not necessarily mean that mouse event
>   listeners on that element cannot or will not be triggered

```js
 $(function(){
  $("#stage-layer").on("wheel",function(e){
   eo=e.originalEvent;
   s=$("#scrollable")
   switch(eo.deltaMode){
    case 0:   //DOM_DELTA_PIXEL  Chrome
     s.scrollTop(eo.deltaY+s.scrollTop())
     s.scrollLeft(eo.deltaX+s.scrollLeft()) 
     break;
    case 1:   //DOM_DELTA_LINE  Firefox
     s.scrollTop(15*eo.deltaY+s.scrollTop()) //scroll(e.deltaX, e.deltaY);  Just a random small amount of scrolling 
     s.scrollLeft(15*eo.deltaX+s.scrollLeft())
     break;
    case 2:   //DOM_DELTA_PAGE
     s.scrollTop(0.03*eo.deltaY+s.scrollTop())
     s.scrollLeft(0.03*eo.deltaX+s.scrollLeft())
     break;
   }
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault()
  })
  
 })
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#stage-layer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}

#application-layer {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid pink;
    pointer-events: none;
}

rect:hover {
    fill: blue;
}

#scrollable {
    overflow: auto;
    color: hotpink;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <svg id="stage-layer">
            <rect width="200" height="200"></rect>
        </svg>
        <div id="application-layer">
            <div id="scrollable">
                <p>foo1</p>
                <p>foo2</p>
                <p>foo3</p>
                <p>foo4</p>
                <p>foo5</p>
                <p>foo6</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**A nice tip:**

This will not probably yield an immediate solution but it is a good choice for long term web development :

> We would like
>   to provide finer grained control (than just auto and none) in HTML ...
>   if you have any particular things that you would like to be able to do
>   with this property, then please add them to the Use Cases section of
>   [this wiki page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/SVG:Pointer-events) (don't worry about keeping it tidy).

**Source : [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)**

Comment: I have used pointer-event in table and overflow in div it fixed the problem. Kindly check my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77314349/12085414).

Answer (score 3):

Translated @user10089632's answer to vanilla javascript

```js
function scroller(event){
  scrollable=document.getElementById("scrollable");
  switch(event.deltaMode){
    case 0:   //DOM_DELTA_PIXEL  Chrome
      scrollable.scrollTop+=event.deltaY
      scrollable.scrollLeft+=event.deltaX
      break;
    case 1:   //DOM_DELTA_LINE  Firefox
      scrollable.scrollTop+=15*event.deltaY
      scrollable.scrollLeft+=15*event.deltaX
      break;
    case 2:   //DOM_DELTA_PAGE
      scrollable.scrollTop+=0.03*event.deltaY
      scrollable.scrollLeft+=0.03*event.deltaX
      break;
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault()
}

document.onwheel = scroller;
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#stage-layer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}

#application-layer {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid pink;
    pointer-events: none;
}

rect:hover {
    fill: blue;
}

#scrollable {
    overflow: auto;
    color: hotpink;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg id="stage-layer">
        <rect width="200" height="200"></rect>
    </svg>
    <div id="application-layer">
        <div id="scrollable">
            <p>foo1</p>
            <p>foo2</p>
            <p>foo3</p>
            <p>foo4</p>
            <p>foo5</p>
            <p>foo6</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```