How to scroll page when mouse is in fixed element and I need pointer events? How to scroll one specific element from anywhere on the page?
I need to scroll one specific element on the page even when the mouse isn't hovering over that element...
I would normally put the div that needs scrolling on the top layer with a transparent background but I have a navigation menu that needs to be seen/interacted with on the same page.
In my experience CSS is extremely finicky; one change that is supposed to be aesthetic only ends up altering how the elements interact with each other and it is frustrating. I am hours into this project and I really don't feel like starting from scratch again just for one bug like this... and having to test if the website works after every CSS addition.
I'll put a jsfiddle of what my website is pretty much structured like.


html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
}

.scrollable {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-left: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="fixed">
    <h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </h1>
    
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable">
    <ul>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>



I can scroll anywhere on the red div and it works, but if I scroll on the blue div the red div won't scroll. Changing the blue div to pointer-events: none; makes it all work (this was the only answer I could find online) except for the fact that I have a navigation bar with pointer events inside the blue div. You would think after being around for centuries HTML would find a simple way to let a fixed element have pointer events AND scroll events!
TL;DR Is there a way to make a scroll anywhere on the screen scroll one specific div?

Building off of 0stone0's answer (with some added stuff to make the scroll more smooth and testing all the pointer events).


// scroll bar functionality for fixed element
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592349/allow-pointer-click-events-to-pass-through-element-whilst-maintaining-scroll-f#
function scroller(event) {
  scrollable = document.getElementById("scrollable");
  switch (event.deltaMode) {
    case 0: //DOM_DELTA_PIXEL       Chrome
      scrollable.scrollTop += event.deltaY
      scrollable.scrollLeft += event.deltaX
      break;
    case 1: //DOM_DELTA_LINE        Firefox
      scrollable.scrollTop += 15 * event.deltaY
      scrollable.scrollLeft += 15 * event.deltaX
      break;
    case 2: //DOM_DELTA_PAGE
      scrollable.scrollTop += 0.03 * event.deltaY
      scrollable.scrollLeft += 0.03 * event.deltaX
      break;
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault()
}

document.onwheel = scroller;


// scroll to an item that inside a div
//   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408920/plain-javascript-scrollintoview-inside-div
function scrollParentToChild(parent, child, threshold = 0) {
  // Where is the parent on page
  const parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
  // What can you see?
  const parentViewableArea = {
    height: parent.clientHeight,
    width: parent.clientWidth,
  };
  // Where is the child
  const childRect = child.getBoundingClientRect();
  // Is the child viewable?
  const isViewableVertically = childRect.top >= parentRect.top &&
    childRect.bottom <= parentRect.top + parentViewableArea.height;
  const isViewableHorizontally = childRect.left >= parentRect.left &&
    childRect.right <= parentRect.left + parentViewableArea.width;
  // if you can't see the child try to scroll parent
  if (!isViewableVertically || !isViewableHorizontally) {
    // Should we scroll using top or bottom? Find the smaller ABS adjustment
    const scrollTop = childRect.top - parentRect.top;
    const scrollBot = childRect.bottom - parentRect.bottom;
    const scrollLeft = childRect.left - parentRect.left;
    const scrollRight = childRect.right - parentRect.right;
    if (Math.abs(scrollTop) < Math.abs(scrollBot) && Math.abs(scrollLeft) < Math.abs(scrollRight)) {
      // we're nearer to the top and left of the list
      parent.scrollTo({
        top: parent.scrollTop + scrollTop - threshold,
        left: parent.scrollLeft + scrollLeft - threshold,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    } else {
      // we're nearer to the bottom and right of the list
      parent.scrollTo({
        top: parent.scrollTop + scrollBot + threshold,
        left: parent.scrollLeft + scrollRight + threshold,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    }
  }
}
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: pink;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#stage-layer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#application-layer {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

rect:hover {
  fill: blue;
}

#scrollable {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  color: hotpink;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  padding-left: 0;
}

p:hover {
  color: white;
  transform: translateX(20px);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.hover:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Blank HTML</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <svg id="stage-layer">
            <rect></rect>
        </svg>
    <div id="application-layer">
      <div class="menu">
        <p onClick="scrollParentToChild(document.getElementById('scrollable'), document.getElementById('first'));">
          go to top of page</p>
        <p onClick="scrollParentToChild(document.getElementById('scrollable'), document.getElementById('last'));">
          go to bottom of page</p>
      </div>

      <div id="scrollable">
        <li id="first">_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li class="hover">HOVER TEST</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li><a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/">LINK TEST</a></li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li>_________</li>
        <li id="last">_________</li>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="/website/test/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




You could use the wheel event to capture 'scroll's on nonscrollable elements, and then translate that to the fixed scrollTop


const s = document.querySelector(".scrollable");
const f = document.querySelector(".fixed");

f.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => (s.scrollTop += (e.deltaY < 1) ? 30 : -30));
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
}

.scrollable {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50vh;
  padding-left: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="fixed">
    <h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </h1>
    
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable">
    <ul>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
       <li>_________</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>




This works decently, thanks. On a small page like this you almost can't tell the difference but on the website I'm making it is clunky. I modified the code a bit to make it feel more like the normal scroll, but it is not going to feel like the normal scroll. Now everyone who goes to my website is gonna wonder why the scroll is all messed up when their mouse passes over a certain spot on the page up and are gonna think whoever made it is trash. I see websites with a similar format to mine and theirs work fine, I seriously wonder how they do it...
