# Can JavaScript capture scroll events, but let clicks pass through?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a setup here, but realized the user has to be able to interact with the layer behind the transparent scroll capture:

http://jsbin.com/huxasup/4/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```
scrollerCapture = document.querySelector('.scroller-capture');
scrollerCapture.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(scrollerCapture.scrollTop);
});
```

Does anyone know of a standard way to do this? Should I use a utlity like iScroll or ScrollMagic to get this effect on mobile devices?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877880/how-do-i-use-pointer-events-to-react-only-to-scroll-event

Comment: Capturing the scroll event should have nothing to do with the click events. Event propagation will have the click events bubble up from the thing clicked to the window.

Comment: No easy solution. The best would probably be to rebuild your markup so that it's not the scroller-container that do scrolls, but an higher container, which would contain both the background and the scroller. You'd then have to make the background sticky.

Comment: Yea I'm thinking to attach the background to the window, like this guy's site http://www.rleonardi.com/interactive-resume/

Answer (score 0):

In your `<div>` tag mention the `onscroll` event. Like for example

```
<div id="someID" onscroll="someFunction();">
```

Then in your corresponding `html` file do the following

```
<script>
function someFunction() {
        //work done when scroll is detected
    };
</script>
```

Thanks. I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think this will work. Same as `document.createElement('div').onscroll` right? I am listening for the 'scroll' event in JavaScript. I would recommend researching Kapeli Dash, it's like a dictionary for coders

Answer (score 0):

You could use

`elementFromPoint()`

to find a DOM at specific mouse coordinates.

> The elementFromPoint() method of the Document interface which returns
>   the topmost element at the specified coordinates.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint

When a DOM element is found, you can execute on click on it.

`element.click()`;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Quick example:

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  var dom = document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);
  dom.click();
})
```

Maybe of your interest, there is a CSS property called:

`pointer-events: none;`

Which allow mouse events to pass through.

> The CSS property pointer-events allows authors to control under what
>   circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the
>   target of mouse events.
>
> In addition to indicating that the element is not the target of mouse
>   events, the value none instructs the mouse event to go "through" the
>   element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: I still can't seem to highlight the text or press the button

Comment: But then the scrolling is disabled.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick :/ Element.click would work only for buttons or anchors, there is no MouseEvent passed to it (no way to get mouse coordinates from the event listener) and implementing a drag (or select-text) function, will be hard. Probably easier to use `pointer-events:none` and listen for mousewheel events, then if we're on top of the scrolling area, well scroll it.