# Allow pointer-events none inside a nested element when the parent is opaque

Tags: html, css

If I do [the following](http://jsfiddle.net/Fy8vD/3470/), then the inner div is scrollable but the select can be changed behind.

```
<div style="
position: fixed;top: 0;left:0;
width: 100px;height: 100px; background-color:rgba(11, 11, 11, 0.6); overflow: scroll;">
  <div style="background-color:rgba(127,255,64,0.6);  width: 200px;height: 200px;pointer-events: none;"></div>
</div>
<select name="" id="select">
  <option value="value1">1</option>
  <option value="value2">2</option>
</select>
```

If I do the following, then the inner div is not scrollable but the select can be changed.

```
<div style="
position: fixed;top: 0;left:0;
width: 100px;height: 100px; background-color:rgba(11, 11, 11, 0.6); overflow: scroll;pointer-events: none;">
  <div style="background-color:rgba(127,255,64,0.6);  width: 200px;height: 200px;"></div>
</div>
<select name="" id="select">
  <option value="value1">1</option>
  <option value="value2">2</option>
</select>
```

How can I have both the select selectable and the area scrollable without moving the div outside the parent div.

EDIT
I can't modify the select (it will be an existing webpage) and the overlay (its an analytical tool) must be on top.

Comment: maybe using z-index? I'll try it on the fiddle.

Comment: Yes, setting `z-index:-1;` on the div worked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fy8vD/3471/

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb thanks but the overlay MUST be on top, the ui below can't sit above

Comment: You could try fading out the select so it _looks_ like it's on bottom.

Comment: simply you can't see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877880/how-do-i-use-pointer-events-to-react-only-to-scroll-event

Answer (score 0):

If you give it `position:absolute` then you can.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fy8vD/3472/

Comment: sorry I can't change what is below the overlay